# What is the button type we can use for message function?

Tags: html, button, input, types, tags

I want to use a `<button>` in a website for a messaging function.
However I am confused with the type of button which I should use. As whether I should use submit, reset or else can I use `<input>` instead of a `<button>`?

Comment: Nowadays a `reset` button is really hardly used. It is used to reset a form. A `submit` button within a `form` (maybe along with a text area) is OK. Using a link with a button style is also a common choice. If you are new to Web dev it is better to focus on more basic questions i.e. make it work first and ignore if it is the best option.

Comment: HI, Welcome to stack overflow. If your question is about which button type to use on a given situation, can you please explain the situation better. The term "message function" might be very broad.
What is a message function ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To have a button in your website, be it for a messaging function or not, both the `<input type="button">` and the `<button>` tags can be used. The difference between the two tags is that the `<button>` tag can hold content such as images and text, whereas, with the `<input>` approach, you cannot (as it is a null element, an empty element, you could say).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about just a button to submit a form or within a live chat using submit would be perfectly fine!

Comment: If it is like on facebook you get the list of friends in the side and a message button besides every friend to message them what could I use.

Comment: Oh for the little button that opens up the chat window you can literally use whatever element you want and just bind a click even to it. A button, and anchor, a span, a div etc.